# Mysql - Order rows that have same columns content

Tags: mysql, sql, database

have a **Mysql** table like that 
id primary key ( idstudy, idarea and  idcategory are foreign keys )

```
**** Table : Operations
id     idstudy   idarea   idcategory  content      lang  
1      22          11       3         content1EN    EN
2      22          11       3         content1FR    FR
3      22          11       3         Content2FR    FR
4      22          11       3         Content2EN    EN
5      35          10       5         Content5EN    EN 
6      35          10       5         Content5FR    FR
7      35          23       12        Content5EN    EN    
8      35          23       12        Content5FR    FR
```

My goal : to assemble language to same row ( FR and EN) to get one row with one column in plus ( ContentEN for example) and remove lang column.

but my problème my table is not in order, and i cant reconnize by id, all i know are idstudy idarea and idcategory but those both are not unique , and sometimes i have 3 rows that are same except (id and content)

I have solution but i dont know how to write it in mysql : is to find all records with ( same idstudy same idarea same idcategory )  in one language then order them by adding column with ( 1 for first result, 2 for the second ...)

**** Table : Operations after order of groups ( idstudy, idarea,  idcategory) in each language with new column ( order)

```
id     idstudy   idarea   idcategory  content      lang     order
1      22          11       3         content1EN    EN       1
2      22          11       3         content1FR    FR       1
3      22          11       3         Content2FR    FR       2
4      22          11       3         Content2EN    EN       1
5      35          10       5         Content5EN    EN       1
6      35          10       5         Content5FR    FR       1
7      35          23       12        Content5EN    EN       1
8      35          23       12        Content5FR    FR       1
```

I just need this result , after to assemble iwill do it using nodejs

note: sorry if my explanation is not so good.

Comment: the 4th row of your example shouldn't be `order=2`? it has the same id's and same language of 1st row

Comment: Why is `order=1` at `id==4` ?

Comment: Thank you for note , i update my question with good table. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, idstudy, idarea, idcategory, content, lang, dense_rank as 'order'
FROM (
    SELECT
      @dense:=IF(@prev_col1=t.idstudy AND @prev_col2=t.idarea AND @prev_col3=t.idcategory AND @prev_col4=t.lang, IF(@prev_col5=t.content, @dense, @dense+1), 1) AS dense_rank,
      t.*,
      @prev_col1:=t.idstudy,  @prev_col2:=t.idarea, @prev_col3:=t.idcategory, @prev_col4:=t.lang, @prev_col5:=t.content
    FROM (SELECT * FROM t1 ORDER BY idstudy, idarea, idcategory, lang, content ) t,
         (SELECT @dense:=1, @prev_col1:=NULL, @prev_col2:=NULL, @prev_col3:=NULL, @prev_col4:=NULL, @prev_col5:=NULL) var
) F
ORDER BY idstudy, idarea, idcategory, lang, content;
```

In MySql you can mimic ms-sql analytics functions in this way [Analytical Function in MySQL - ROW_NUMBER, RANK, DENSE_RANK](http://kennethxu.blogspot.it/2016/04/analytical-function-in-mysql-rownumber.html)

In SQL-Sever you could use DENSE_RANK()

```
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY idstudy, idarea, idcategory, lang ORDER BY content) [order]
FROM tableName
```

Comment: OP stated that he is using Mysql and not SqlServer

Comment: the answer is complete

Comment: thank you MtwStark , im trying to understand all that, im not expert in Mysql, so it will take a time :)

Comment: I have edited the answer to be simpler to read. take the 1st `SELECT` statemente and change `Table1` with your table name, the 1st column should be what you need

Comment: Im using Mysql but i really dont understand how can i dot that!
I have one question : col1, col2,  col3 i have 4 columns that should be same to rank rows . 

can you help me please to translate your code with names of my table columns , how to set rank in column 'order' ?


id-----idstudy-----idarea-----idcategory----content--------lang------ order

and idstudy--idarea-idcategory-lang should be same to make the order of group

Thank you a lot

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect **EXACTLY** your columns, only change `T1` with your table name. let me know

Answer (score 0):

Fianllay i found another solution , i made two tables with same structure ( french and english), regenerate id of eeach table ( to be 1.2.3.for each).

As i have 500 rows in each table i checked each row if its Ok ( each id must concern same content in two languages )

Special thanks to @MtwStark for his time :) i appreciate your help

Sometimes when we try to explain our problem we find the solution :)

Comment: Thank you for your disponibility and your support :)